# Force Band to only notify for one mailbox

Tags: notifications, microsoft-band

I have my phone set to sync with two mailboxes. One of them is set to display banners and buzz for incoming mail. The other just drops an item in the Notification Center.

When I got my Band, it started off notifying me for both mailboxes even though I only really want to be alerted for the one. I tried disabling notifications for the second mailbox entirely on the phone, but Band still buzzes and logs incoming messages for it.

I know there's the VIP function that will allow me to select specific senders that I want to be notified for. But my primary mailbox is not really noisy at all, and I don't want to be restricted to getting notifications for a pre-selected group of senders.

Is there a way to restrict Band notifications on a per-mailbox level, without having to disconnect the mailbox from the phone entirely?

Band Build: 10.3.3213.0 09 R
Microsoft Health Version: 1.3.10702.3

Phone: Nokia Lumia 920
Firmware Name: Lumia Denim
Firmware Revision: 3051.50009.1425.2001

OS Name: Windows Phone 8.1 Update
OS Version: 8.10.14157.200